# Aztec barcode with binary data using ZPL

Tags: java, zpl, aztec-barcode

Is is possible to use ZPL and binary data for aztec barcode?

I try BluetoothConnection write to send joined array of String encoded in UTF8 and byte data/

```
String zplStart;
byte[] aztecData;
String endZpl;

new BluetoothConnection(MAC).write(zplStart.getBytes + aztecData + endZpl);
```

A expect printed aztec with byte data.

Comment: Can you add an example of your binary data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used UTF8 encoding (^CI28) because my texts on label was using central Europe fonts. Do not know whats the problem with encoding in aztec, because byte of data are always just bytes of data. So I change encoding back to default before aztec and return UTF8 just after aztec and everything is OK.